# Pick file from storage in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I'm developing an app and I need to upload an image and file. The image was successfully done when I use `react-native-image-picker` library and use `RNFetchBlob` to upload to the server. But I'm still confuse in how to pick a file in react-native.

Is the process is same with how upload image, I pick the picture from storage and get the uri of that image and send it to server, or something like what?

Can you help me how to upload a file and what's the library i can use to do it?

Thanks

Comment: So you want to store an image on your server using `RNFetchBlob` ?

Comment: The type of file is irrelevant while uploading it. And you did not tell if it was a file that you uploaded after having picked an 'image'. So explain better please.

Answer (score 2):

RNFetchBlob can do it. You can try this:

```
RNFetchBlob.android.getContentIntent('application/octet-stream').then((path) => {
    // do your work with this path
})
```

But I think there is a bug in this function when your MainActivity is FragmentActivity, it will throw the IllegalArgumentException("Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode").

Have a try~